# Установка Siebel

Tags: oracle

Прошу подсказать где скачать siebel и что нужно сказать для установки, а то посмотрел видос по установке, но так и не понял где взять siebel enterprise server
Заранее благодарю

Comment: Судя по поиску - это жутко кровавый энтерпрайз. Тебе зачем? Ну и если напрямую отвечать на вопрос - вот тут должно быть: https://edelivery.oracle.com/osdc/faces/Home.jspx

Comment: Скачать скачал, теперь проблема с установкой. Не могу понять где взять keystore (для установки Siebel Enterprise Server). Подскажите как это сделать и где

Comment: Ты так и не рассказал зачем тебе такой специфичный продукт.

Comment: Хочу интеграцию научиться дома делать

Comment: Скачать скачал, теперь проблема с установкой. Не могу понять где взять keystore (для установки Siebel Enterprise Server). Подскажите как это сделать и где

Comment: Эммм... интеграцию чего?

Comment: Например, с Diasoft. Вы мне ответите про установку или нет?

Comment: `Diasoft` это тот который на Википедии? Ну т.е. один кровавый энтерпрайз ты хочешь подружить с другим таким же? Ну тут явно пахнет официальным саппортом, контрактами и камазом денег. Вряд ли тут сидят те, кто и ковырял это и захочет поделиться опытом. Реально, быстрее Ораклу написать.

Comment: Спасибо, понятно, значит спрошу у Оракла саппорт

Comment: Расскажи потом во что вылилось. Реально интересно.